# SQL Subquery Help

Tags: subquery

I am little stumped on what to do with this query. The POs attached to them should only total as 1600 left open of that part number. However, instead it generates multiple rows unnecessarily. The problem appears to be the inventory ordered column/section of the query. I have tried using `sum() over partition by` as well to no avail.

The result is:
[image: First Try]

The code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.classid, 
                l.whseloc, 
                l.invtid, 
                l.qtyonhand, 
                Sum(CASE 
                      WHEN f.mrpflag = 0 THEN l.qtyonhand 
                      ELSE 0 
                    END) 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY l.invtid) AS TotalNonNet, 
                ( p.qtyord - p.qtyrcvd )   AS InventoryOrdered, 
                Sum(l.qtyonhand * f.mrpflag) 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY l.invtid) AS TotalNet 
FROM   opslocation l (nolock) 
       JOIN opsinventory i (nolock) 
         ON l.invtid = i.invtid 
       JOIN opsamloctable f (nolock) 
         ON l.whseloc = f.whseloc 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.opspurorddet (nolock) p 
              ON l.invtid = p.invtid 
WHERE  l.qtyonhand <> 0
```

The result I want is:

[image: Result Wanted]

I appreciate the help.

Comment: update tags with which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back here and update your question.  At a minimum you need to provide sample raw data and the associated wrong/right results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a regular `SUM` with `GROUP BY`, instead of a windowed function:

```
SELECT  i.classid,
        l.whseloc,
        l.invtid,
        l.qtyonhand,
        SUM(CASE WHEN f.MRPFlag = 0 THEN l.qtyonhand ELSE 0 END) TotalNonNet,
        SUM(p.qtyord-p.qtyrcvd) InventoryOrdered,
        SUM(l.qtyonhand * f.mrpflag) TotalNet
FROM opslocation l (nolock)
INNER JOIN opsinventory i (nolock) 
    ON l.invtid = i.invtid
INNER JOIN opsamloctable f (nolock) 
    ON l.whseloc = f.whseloc
LEFT JOIN dbo.opspurorddet (nolock) p 
    ON l.InvtID = p.InvtID
WHERE l.qtyonhand <> 0
GROUP BY i.classid,
         l.whseloc,
         l.invtid,
         l.qtyonhand;
```